# jQuery Mobile + IE + browser redirect

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, mobile, redirect

I am developing an app with jQuery Mobile which also is working for desktop.

It works fine but I am having an issue with IE for desktop. The issue (only with IE) is that when ajax is enabled a hash appears in the browser bar and this adds a side effects.

One side effect of not updating the address bar is for example you login on the site and you are on /user/login page and the address bar shows it up correctly. Then the server performs a redirection to /myinfo after login which goes to the myinfo page but in the browser address bar '/user/login' stays.

If you click on a link the address bar changes correctly.

But if you want to do a server redirection, in address bar you see '/user/login staying'. You are in /myinfo but you see /user/login in the address bar.

If you happen to come to myinfo with clicking on other links before, IE adds '#' tag for example /user/login#myinfo.

Coming to myinfo, you fill out the form and hit submit. Because in the browser bar you have /user/login#myinfo, the form is not submitted because web2py thinks you are in /user/login.

Now, this is only with jQuery Mobile+IE. When I am using jQuery (not adding Mobile), it works properly.

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
--Constantine

Comment: I believe this is the usual behaviour, since the new pages are loaded into the DOM via AJAX and you are not leaving the page. You'll need to disabled AJAX in the mobile porperties (see prototype/defaults documentation of JQM) **or** declare specific link as _external_ with `rel="external"`  / `data-ajax="false"`. http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Disabling Ajax adds another complication - buttons does not work under IE Desktop.